# Slow Scenekit Performance

Tags: ios, performance, swift, scenekit

I am creating this sort of first person shooter game for the iPhone 6 Plus, but when I introduce any lights to the scene, the frame rate goes from an already barely acceptable 12fps to an absolutely unplayable 2fps. Also, introducing a particle system with more than ten particles in it takes the frame rate to 9fps. I have already made it so that it adds all the walls and doors to a map node, and then flattens it using flattenedClone and adds that. I am unsure what else I can do without switching to Metal. But I am also wondering about this because if SceneKit were so slow, why would it even exist?
[image: Scenekit Stats]

Comment: measuring fps in simulator renders the question moot. run it on a device!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about measuring performance in a simulated environment, not the actual target hardware.

Comment: How's that? (I don't have a developer license yet anyway)

Comment: google it ;) you'll have an answer in no time. You better get a dev license & iphone 6+ if you want to continue with the project. But you'll probably get 60 fps if you do that.

Comment: The iOS Simulator runs OpenGL ES with a software renderer, so anything that uses OpenGL ES (like SpriteKit or SceneKit) is going to have ***very*** different performance characteristics than it would on an actual device. (And if they somehow ran GLES using the host Mac's GPU, you'd still have different performance than on a device, just in the other direction and/or in different dimensions.) It can't be said enough: ***Never rely on the simulator for performance questions***, especially when GPU use is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved: get a developer licence!

Comment: How did that help

Comment: So that I can load my app onto my phone. The simulator is far too slow.

Comment: Of course, nowadays you can just directly plug your phone in and put your app on it from XCode w/o a dev license.

Comment: Yeah. The game I'm making runs slow on iPhone 5s and below, which is annoying. I came here to see if this was a solution and I saw that and thought it was a joke. How'd the game turn out?

Comment: Okay. I don't have any skill in art so it basically stayed looking like crap, but it was a fun shooter game. I mostly did it in response to the WWDC announcement of Swift & SceneKit, to test that stuff out.

Comment: Yeah, I am awful at art as well. I'm just using the basic shapes that come with SceneKit, which is baffling me why the FPS drops so low. It looks like, using statistics, that the Physics engine is getting called a lot.